# Global index of output

Tags: blockchain, transaction-data, txpool, output-selection

Can anyone please tell me, is there a way to find out the future global index of the output that is currently in the tx pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. It will be set when the transaction is mined.

Comment: That is, the algorithm for selecting transactions from tx_pool when creating a block is non-deterministic, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Outputs in the tx pool are selected via sorting by fee and time. https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/d7bac99f6fd1ad8e3f3c90785a3f5b7d77e73cc5/src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp#L1151